# Python: for loop in index assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, variable-assignment

While working through the awesome book "Programming Collective Intelligence", by Toby Segaran, I've encountered some techniques in index assignments I'm not entirely familiar with.

Take this for example:

```
createkey='_'.join(sorted([str(wi) for wi in wordids]))
```

or:

```
normalizedscores = dict([(u,float(l)/maxscore) for (u,l) in linkscores.items()])
```

All the nested tuples in the indexes have me a bit confused.  What is actually being assigned to these varibles?  I assumed obviously the `.join` one comes out as a string, but what about the latter?  If someone could explain the mechanics of these loops I'd really appreciate it.  I assume these are pretty common techniques, but being new to Python, I suppose to ask is a moment's shame.  Thanks!

Comment: Everyone is mentioning that those are list comprehensions. What people aren't mentioning is that those examples are _wrong_ and that those square brackets should be left off -- they should be generator expressions instead, which are the same except they only yield values as needed, instead of storing them all in a list. Since you're just using the lists immediately then throwing them away, you'd be better off just using generator expressions.

Comment: @agf could you give an example?  I'm new to this approach.  Thanks!

Comment: Just replace the square brackets with parenthesis, and the `sorted` and `dict` functions will ask for one value at a time, which the generator expression will give, instead of storing them all in a temporary list.

Comment: Doesn't `sorted()` build a list anyway?

Comment: @agf: I just timed it, and `sorted()` takes about 10 % longer on a generator expression than on a list.

Comment: @TimPietzcker But with a list comprehension the list has to exist twice, instead of once. What version is that on? List comprehensions are basically `list()` around a generator expression on Python 3.2+ (?) but I wouldn't be surprised by a 10% difference on earlier versions.

Comment: @agf: No, it doesn't have to exist twice. It is built during the list comprehension and passed as a parameter to `sorted()` (which then returns a new list). With a genex, `sorted()` first has to build a list from the genex' results, and then construct a list that it returns. I had timed this on Python 3.2.2 where the effect is more pronounced than on Python 2.7.2 (I have included the timings in my newly edited answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
[str(wi) for wi in wordids]
```

is a **[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)**.

```
a = [str(wi) for wi in wordids]
```

is the same as

```
a = []
for wi in wordids:
    a.append(str(wi))
```

So

```
createkey='_'.join(sorted([str(wi) for wi in wordids]))
```

creates a list of strings from each item in `wordids`, then sorts that list and joins it into a big string using `_` as a separator.

As agf rightly noted, you can also use a generator expression, which looks just like a list comprehension but with parentheses instead of brackets. This avoids construction of a list if you don't need it later (except for iterating over it). And if you already have parentheses there like in this case with `sorted(...)` you can simply remove the brackets.

However, in this special case you won't be getting a performance benefit (in fact, it'll be about 10 % slower; I timed it) because `sorted()` will need to build a list anyway, but it looks a bit nicer:

```
createkey='_'.join(sorted(str(wi) for wi in wordids))
```

---

```
normalizedscores = dict([(u,float(l)/maxscore) for (u,l) in linkscores.items()])
```

iterates through the items of the dictionary `linkscores`, where each item is a key/value pair. It creates a list of key/`l/maxscore` tuples and then turns that list back into a dictionary.

However, since Python 2.7, you could also use **[dict comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax)**:

```
normalizedscores = {u:float(l)/maxscore for (u,l) in linkscores.items()}
```

---

Here's some timing data:

**Python 3.2.2**

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="a = '_'.join(sorted([str(x) for x in n]))", setup="import random; n = [random.randint(0,1000) for i in range(100)]")
61.37724242267409
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="a = '_'.join(sorted(str(x) for x in n))", setup="import random; n = [random.randint(0,1000) for i in range(100)]")
66.01814811313774
```

**Python 2.7.2**

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="a = '_'.join(sorted([str(x) for x in n]))", setup="import random; n = [random.randint(0,1000) for i in range(100)]")
58.01728623923137
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt="a = '_'.join(sorted(str(x) for x in n))", setup="import random; n = [random.randint(0,1000) for i in range(100)]")
60.58927580777687
```

Comment: @andronikus Nope. Python 2.7.

Comment: I think the author probably was using an older version of python at the time of writing, because I downloaded the revised example code from his blog and in there he uses the dictionary comprehension method you described.

Comment: Oh, I'll be damned: http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features.  Objection withdrawn!

Comment: @andronikus: I have made my answer a bit clearer, thanks. After all, Python 2.5 and 2.6 are still widely used...

Comment: Yeah, I think I still use one of those.  It doesn't help that I've never heard of dict comprehensions until now.  Pretty cool!

Answer (score 3):

Let's take the first one:

1. `str(wi) for wi in wordids` takes each element in `wordids` and converts it to string.
2. `sorted(...)` sorts them (lexicographically).
3. `'_'.join(...)` merges the sorted word ids into a single string with underscores between entries.

Now the second one:

```
normalizedscores = dict([(u,float(1)/maxscore) for (u,l) in linkscores.items()])
```

1. `linkscores` is a dictionary (or a dictionary-like object).
2. `for (u,l) in linkscores.items()` iterates over all entries in the dictionary, for each entry assigning the key and the value to `u` and `l`.
3. `(u,float(1)/maxscore)` is a tuple, the first element of which is `u` and the second element is `1/maxscore` (to me, this looks like it might be a typo: `float(l)/maxscore` would make more sense -- note the lowercase letter el in place of one).
4. `dict(...)` constructs a dictionary from the list of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is taken as the key and the second is taken as the value.

In short, it makes a copy of the dictionary, preserving the keys and dividing each value by `maxscore`.

Comment: +2 if you explain what list comps basically do (I have the feeling the OP is not aware of it, but I may be wrong)

Answer (score 1):

The latter is equivalent to:

```
normalizedscores = {}
for u, l in linkscores.items():
    normalizedscores[u] = float(l) / maxscore
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(u,float(1)/maxscore) for (u,l) in linkscores.items()]
```

This creates a list by iterating over the tuples in `linkscores.items()` and computing `(u, float(l)/maxscore)` for each tuple.

```
dict([this list])
```

creates a `dict` with entries from the result of the list comprehension - `(u, float(l)/maxscore)` for each item in `linkscores`.

As another example of creating a dict from a list of tuples:

```
>>> l = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
>>> d = dict(l)
>>> d
{1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the first...example

```
>>> wordids = [1,2,4,3,10,7]
>>> createkey='_'.join(sorted([str(wi) for wi in wordids]))
>>> print createkey
1_10_2_3_4_7
```

What it is doing is iterating through the list with a for loop, sorting the list, then joins all of the sorted values into a string, separating values with '_'

Answer (score 1):

The weird-looking business happening inside the `[]` brackets is called a list comprehension, and it is basically a really concise way of building a list.  `myList = [str(wi) for wi in wordids]` is equivalent to:

```
myList = []

for wi in wordids:
  myList.append(str(wi))
```

`sorted()` then sorts that list, and `join()` gives a string with those list items separated by underscores, like this: `item1_item2_item3_...`.

The second assignment is more complicated/concise, but here's what's going on:

- `linkscores` looks like a dictionary, and the `items()` method returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples from the dictionary.  So `for (u,l) in linkscores.items()` is looping over that list.
- For each of those tuples, we create a new tuple containing `(u, float(l)/maxscore)`, and add it to the list.  So this step basically changes your `(item, value)` list to a list of `(item, normalized value)` tuples.
- The `dict()` function turns that back into a dictionary.

The overall result of this is to take all the values in the dict and normalize them.  There may be an easier/more verbose way to do this, but this way has the benefit of looking cool.  I prefer to not do crazy stuff with list comprehensions because it hurts readability, so don't feel bad at all if you don't feel like writing this kind of thing yourself!